# Importing csv into multiple mysql databases from rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, resque, sidekiq

I have a CSV file consisting of 78,000 records.Im using smarter_csv (https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) to parse the csv file. I want to import that into a MySQL database from my rails app. I have the following two questions

1. What would be the best approach to quickly importing such a large data-set into MySQL from my rails app ?. Would using resque or sidekiq to create multiple workers be a good idea ?
2. I need to insert this data into a given table which is present in multiple databases. In Rails, i have a model talk to only one database. So how can i scale the solution to talk to multiple mysql databases from my model ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the native interface of the database application itself for importing and exporting; it would be optimised for that specific purpose.

For MySQL, the [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) provides that interface. Note that the import can also be done as an SQL statement and that this executable provides a much saner interface for the underlying SQL command.

As far as implementation goes, if this is a frequent import exercise, the sidekiq/resque/cron job is the best possible approach.

[EDIT]

The SQL command referred to above is the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) as the other answer points out.

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise probably the best method is the use MYSQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) syntax and execute an import command on each database. This requires the data file to be local to each database instance.

As the other answer suggests, `mysqlimport` can be used to ease the import as the LOAD DATA INFILE statement syntax is highly customisable and can deal with many data formats.