# How to upload multiple csv file in mysql database using ssh command?

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I want to upload the multiple csv file in mysql database using ssh command.
Is that possible ?
If yes then please tell me the commands.

Thanks

Comment: Uploading files with ssh (scp) is one thing. Importing in your database is another. You need a combination of `scp` (to copy)  and `mysqlimport` (to import into mysql). But your question is not a programming question and so it does not belong on stack overflow. Try superuser or serverfault instead.

Answer (score 2):

As to how to import CSV file into MySQL, see this [Importing csv into multiple mysql databases from rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925707/importing-csv-into-multiple-mysql-databases-from-rails-app/19925888)

Yes, it is possible to do it via SSH. Assuming the data file is on host1 and the database is on host2, you'd need to

1) Copy the data file from host1 to host2

`scp data.csv user@host2:/tmp/data.csv`

2) SSH in to host2, connect to MySQL and execute the import command.

`ssh user@host2 'mysql -udbuser -pdbpass -e "LOAD DAT INFILE ..."'`

Comment: Fulop In my case i have all csv files in my server. and upload in the mysql database. Please give me commands to import the all csv files in my database.

Comment: I cannot give you the exact command as it depends on the format and structure of the data file and the tables schemata in your database.

Comment: Is this possible to import the all csv files from one directory? using the SSH cammands.

Comment: My friend, you cannot expect us to give you the the code you need that works as you expect and you don't even have to look at it or try to understand it just copy paste and go... Do try and read/understand how to use the right syntax for your needs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. You can do this with a MySQL database as follows:

1. Log onto your box via ssh:

   ssh your-server-name -l your-user-name
2. Secure copy your CSV file over if it's not already on your server.

   scp your-user-name@your-computer:/path/to/local/file /path/to/remote/file
3. Run mysql via the command line

   mysql -u username -pPassword your-db-name
4. Run the following command in you mysql console:

   LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/remote/file.csv' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES STARTING BY 'xxx';

For more information check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

This is also easy to do when importing data using [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)

Comment: Is this possible to import the all csv files data in mysql databse from one directory (folder)? using the SSH cammands.

Comment: Yes, if the file names don't change you could create an shell script to so this. Basically you'll save all you commands in a text file and save it with a .sh extension and start the file off the the line "#!/bin/bash". If you wanted to automate the import then setting up a cron job would you're after.